# Determine if the following subsets in $\mathbb R^4$ are connected, path-connected, compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness, path-connected

I am trying to solve the following problem (not homework):

Equip $\mathbb R^4$ with the standard topology induced with the Euclidean metric and let $f:\mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the function given by $$f((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1^2 - x_2^2 + x_3^2 - x_4^2.$$
Define the sets
$A = f^{-1}(\{1\}), B = A \cap \{x \in \mathbb R^4 : x_2^2 + x_4^2 = 1\}$ and $C = f^{-1}((0,\infty)) \cap \{x \in \mathbb R^4: x_2=x_3=x_4=0 \}$.

I need to determine whether the following statements are true or false.

a) $A$ is compact,

b) $B$ is compact,

c) $B$ is path-connected,

d) $C$ is connected

I have managed to get an answer for a), b) and d), although I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. On c) I got completely stuck, so any hints or answers would be appreciated. Here is my attempt:

a) The singleton $\{1\}$ is closed under the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ $\Rightarrow A = f^{-1}(\{1\}) $ is closed in the standard topology on $\mathbb R^4$ if $f$ is continuous. Since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous. However, $A$ is not bounded (there is no upper limit to the distance between two points that satisfy the equation $x_1^2 - x_2^2 + x_3^2 - x_4^2 = 1 \iff x_1^2 + x_3^2 = 1 + x_2^2 + x_4^2 $). Heine-Borel states that for $K \subseteq \mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^n$ equipped with the standard topology we have: $K$ compact $\iff K$ closed and bounded. Hence, A cannot be compact.

b) $A$ is the set of points $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ for which $x_1^2 - x_2^2 + x_3^2 - x_4^2 = 1$. To get $B$, we only want to keep the points where $x_2^2 + x_4^2 = 1$, hence $B = \{x \in \mathbb R^4: x_1^2+x_3^2=0, x_2^2 + x_4^2 = 1 \}$, or more simply $B = \{x \in \mathbb R^4: x_1 = x_3 = 0, x_2^2 + x_4^2 = 1 \}$. We can say that $B$ is closed (since its compliment is open). It is also bounded (it is a cirlce in $\mathbb R^4$ space). By Heine-Borel's theorem I then conclude that $B$ is compact.

c) I have no idea where to begin here. I was initially thinking of the theorem: An open set in $\mathbb R^n$ is connected if and only if it is path-connected. However, to me $B = \{x \in \mathbb R^4: x_1 = x_3 = 0, x_2^2 + x_4^2 = 1 \}$ seems to be closed by the same reasoning as above. Also, $B$ seems to be connected so I can't use that to disprove that it is not path-connected.

d) $C$ is the set of points for which $x_1^2 - x_2^2 + x_3^2 - x_4^2 > 0$ and $x_2=x_3=x_4=0 \iff x_1^2 > 0, x_2=x_3=x_4=0 \iff x_1 \neq 0, x_2=x_3=x_4=0$, that is $C=(-\infty,\infty)\setminus 0 \times \{0\}^3$. A possible seperation for this set would be $U = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{r=1}^d(x=(i,0,0,0))$ and $U = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{r=1}^d(x=(-i,0,0,0))$ where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^4$. Now $C \subseteq U \cup V, U \cap V = \varnothing, U \cap C \neq \varnothing \neq V \cap C$. Hence $C$ is not connected.

Please let me know if any clarification is needed, thanks.

Comment: B) is the intersection of the “circles” $x_1^2+x_3^2=2$ and $x_2^2+x_4^2=1$

Comment: @FShrike Oh yes, you are right, my bad. But even in this case we have a closed and bounded set, hence $B$ is still compact, correct?

Comment: Freakish has addressed that point. A product of connected compact spaces is connected and compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3, x_4)\ |\ x_1^2-x_2^2+x_3^2-x_4^2=1\}$. Then $B$ is defined by the following system of equations

$$\begin{cases}
x_1^2-x_2^2+x_3^2-x_4^2=1 \\
x_2^2+x_4^2=1
\end{cases}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}
x_1^2+x_3^2=2 \\
x_2^2+x_4^2=1
\end{cases}$$

or in other words $B$ is homeomorphic to product of two spheres $S^1\times S^1$ via the following map:

$$S^1\times S^1\to B$$
$$\big((x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4)\big)\mapsto \big(\sqrt{2}\cdot x_1, x_3,\sqrt{2}\cdot x_2, x_4\big)$$

I leave as an exercise that this is a homeomorphism. This should answer both path-connectedness and compactness questions.

Your other reasonings seem to be fine.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @freakish! My idea on how to prove the mapping is a homeomorphism: 1) It is clearly bijective. One could prove this by picking two points $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4), x'=(x'_1,x'_2,x'_3,x'_4)$ and show that they are mapped to the same point iff $x=x'$. 2) It is continuous since the mapping is differentiable for each variable $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ since differentiability implies continuity.  3) The inverse mapping is defined as (I think): $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \mapsto (\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}x_1,x_3,\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}x_2,x_4)$. Similarly one can show this to be continuous.

Comment: However, I am not sure I understand why the mapping has to be a homeomorphism, is not sufficient that it is a continuous mapping? My reasoning: One can construct the set $B$ by mapping the cartesian product of $S^1$ with $S^1$. The circles are path-connected/compact. The cartesian product of path-connected/compact spaces is in itself path-connected/compact, hence $S^1 \times S^1$ is path-connected/compact. The continuous image of a path-connected/compact space is also path-connected/compact. Hence if we can show that the mapping $S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow B$ is continuous, we are done?

Comment: @Ashar surjective continuous. Yes, it is enough.